# Opening multiple instances of the same dialog programatically in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, dialog, multiple-instances

Title says it all.

Can I invoke method like:

```
void myMethod()
{ 
    PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("objectInfoPage"); 
}
```

so each time I do this, new dialog will appear ?
Right now I have to close previous instance in order open new one.

Comment: You might want to look at doing it dynamically using the PF Dialog Framework: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml

Comment: Does myMethod method provided in example differs in any way from mentioned Dialog Framework?

Comment: I thought the Dialog Framework had a way of creating new dialogs and referencing them dynamically not just opening a dialog you already constructed.  Maybe I am wrong though.